# Remove previous selection highlighting in RichTextBox without scrolling

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, highlight

I have a form with a RichTextBox (RTB) and a listBox.

When the end user selects an item in the listbox, any matched text in the RTB is highlighted (full code removed for brevity).

```
re = New Regex(txtToFind)

For Each m In re.Matches(rtbMain.Text)
    rtbMain.[Select](m.Index, m.Length)
    rtbMain.SelectionColor = Color.White
    rtbMain.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight
Next
```

When the user left mouse clicks in the RTB I want the previously highlighted text to be cleared.  This is the standard windows behaviour - If you manually select some text in an RTB with the mouse, it is highlighted, click anywhere back in the RTB and the highlighting disappears. My programatically selected text remains selected.

I have some partially working code (below). I can clear all the highlighted text, but it is by process of selecting everything, changing the colour back and then deselecting it again.  I know it is not efficient, the RTB flickers and I am sure it is not the correct way to do it.  Can I emulate the standard windows behaviour?

Also using my code, it scrolls to the first line when entering the RTB a second time.

I get around this the first time by returning the top visible line index before clearing the text and then selecting that line again afterwards and using ScrollToCaret().  This only works on the first pass.  Subsequent MouseDown events select the top row regardless of where the user has clicked so nothing can be manually highlighted in the RTB.

```
Private Sub rtbMain_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles rtbMain.MouseDown

    Dim topIndex As Integer = rtbMain.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New System.Drawing.Point(1, 1))
    Dim topLine As Integer = rtbMain.GetLineFromCharIndex(topIndex)

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        'Do nothing (Context Menu)
    Else
        rtbMain.SelectAll()
        rtbMain.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        rtbMain.SelectionBackColor = Color.White
        rtbMain.DeselectAll()
        rtbMain.Select(topIndex, 0)
        rtbMain.ScrollToCaret()
    End If

End Sub
```

I need my code to emulate the standard windows behaviour - clear selected text highlighting on MouseDown and leave the mouse cursor where the user has clicked.

Any help anyone can offer is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this one.

In the right click event, try RtbMain.SelectionLength = 0